# Pyspark aggregate a StructType column as an Array of its elements for each line

Tags: python, pyspark, aggregate, apache-spark-2.3

I'm trying to do something that seems pretty much straightforward but somehow cannot figure how to do it with pyspark.

I have a df with two columns (to simplify) 'id' and 'strcol', with possible duplicates ids

I want to do a df.groupBy('id') that would return for each id an array of the strcol values

simple exemple :

```
|--id--|--strCol--|
|   a  |  {'a':1} |
|   a  |  {'a':2} |
|   b  |  {'b':3} |
|   b  |  {'b':4} |
|------|----------|
would become
|--id--|-------aggsStr------|
|   a  |  [{'a':1},{'a':2}] |
|   b  |  [{'b':3},{'b':4}] |
|------|--------------------|
```

I tried to use apply with a pandas udf but it seems to refuse to return arrays. (or maybe I didn't use it correctly)

Comment: It might be yes, it didn't came up on my searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) from the `pyspark.sql.functions` module:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
agg = df.groupby("id").agg(F.collect_list("strCol"))
```

A fully functional example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data =  {'id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'strCol': [{'a':1}, {'a':2}, {'b':3}, {'b':4}]}

df_aux = pd.DataFrame(data)

# df type: DataFrame[id: string, strCol: map<string,bigint>]
df = spark.createDataFrame(df_aux) 


# agg type: # DataFrame[id: string, collect_list(strCol): array<map<string,bigint>>]
agg = df.groupby("id").agg(F.collect_list("strCol"))
```

Hope this helped!